# jQuery sortable not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to allow users to rearrange `<li>` in a `<ul>` list.  HTML only contains

```
<ul id="uisortable"></ul>
```

And the javascript contains this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#uisortable').sortable();
    $("#uisortable").disableSelection();
});
```

The items are added dynamically from JS and after adding the items, I'm calling

$('#uisortable').sortable("refresh");

Everything works perfectly fine in FF, Opera and Webkit, but does not work at all in IE - any version, even IE 9.  I tried adding `activate` option to the `sortable` like this:

```
$('#uisortable').sortable({
    activate: function() {
        throw("Start sorting");
    }
});
```

In IE 9 script debugger, I put a breakpoint on line `throw("Start sorting")` - but that line never activates.  It seems like in IE the sortable is simply not attaching itself to the list.

I'm using jquery 1.4.2 with jquery UI 1.8.13.

Interestingly, jquery ui sortable demo page works fine, so it's got to be something with my code - but how much further can I simplify it?  Ok, I can - so I did.  Instead of dynamically creating the items, I created them statically (for testing) in my HTML.  I removed everything from the `<li>` except one line of text.  Now my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="uisortable">
    <li class="sortitem">Item 1</li>
    <li class="sortitem">Item 2</li>
    <li class="sortitem">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

With the above javascript code.  Still, not working in IE.  And no errors of any kind in the error console.  Fine in FF, Webkit and Opera though.  I'm totally stumped now.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not use a more recent version of jQuery?

Comment: @Blazemonger I wouldn't want to go there right now.  There are thousands of pages on the site, about half of them depend on jquery.  If I change jquery version, I'd have to retest thousands of pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was related to the jquery.ui version.  I upgraded from 1.8.13 to 1.8.20 (much easier than upgrading jquery from 1.4.2 to 1.7.2) - and now it works!

Comment: Yes, but oddly I've updated the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/edmM7/9/) to use JQuery 1.4.2 & 1.8.13... and it still works for me in IE9.

Comment: @Holf The wonders of IE :)  It works now - and I'm not touching it any more!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked once we changed the version for jqueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edmM7/).

Works fine for me in IE9 with JQuery 1.4.4. But, if I drop to JQuery 1.3.2 (the next lower version available on JSFiddle), it stops working.

You can 'Add Resources' on JSFiddle to pull in the exact versions you're using, but I think using JQuery 1.4.4 or later (with the appropriate version of JQueryUI) would fix it.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 requires an older version of jQuery-UI.